# android Image crop Could not find documentation

Tags: android

I have to implement image cropping in my application, I get a lot help from stack overflow and other resources but unable to find documentation from android help site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Android SDK for image cropping, which is why you will not find documentation on image cropping. You will either need to implement that yourself, or use any number of image cropping libraries available for Android.

A variety of such libraries show up with a Web search on `android image cropping library`, such as [this one](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop), [this one](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper), and [this one](https://bitbucket.org/duhrer/android-image-cropping-library).

Comment: thanks, but here[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261498/android-kitkat-image-crop] I have implemented cropping without any library import without. but the problem is, it gives error some time....

Comment: @NaveedAli: "it gives error some time" -- in part, that is because [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). Use a library or write your own cropping code, please.

Comment: if it is true then why cropping is working well in android 4.1.2 and android 4.2.2

Comment: @NaveedAli: It may be working on the device or two that you tried. There are *thousands* of Android devices. Not all will have that particular app, or they may have removed that activity from the app, or they may have changed that activity to behave differently.