# Android 4.4.2 - camera uri return null and also cropping feature not working?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image, android-gallery, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to click image from camera and show into imageview but onactivityresult URI return null. BUt below code runs fine on JellyBean , ICS with cropping feature .

**Calling intent**

```
                Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
                pickIntent.setType("image/*");
                pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                pickIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                String pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture";
                // startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 1);
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]
                { captureIntent });
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, GlobalVariables.GALLERY_MODE);
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                // user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
                if (requestCode == GlobalVariables.GALLERY_MODE)
                {
                    // get the Uri for the captured image
                    picUri = data.getData();
                    System.out.println("picUri      =======     => "+picUri);
                    boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
                    if(isKitKat)
                    {
                        System.out.println(new GraphicsUtil().getPath(RegistrationActivity.this, picUri));
                        String filePath = new GraphicsUtil().getPath(RegistrationActivity.this, picUri);
                        System.out.println("filepath            => "+filePath);
                        bitmapPreview = null;
                        bitmapPreview = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                        System.out.println("bitmapPreview           => "+bitmapPreview );
                        imageViewUser.setImageBitmap(new GraphicsUtil().getCircleBitmap(GraphicsUtil.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(filePath,
                                120, 120)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        performCrop(picUri, PIC_CROP, RegistrationActivity.this);
                    }
                }
                // user is returning from cropping the image
                else if (requestCode == PIC_CROP)
                {
                    String filePath = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/temporary_holder.jpg").getAbsolutePath();
                    bitmapPreview = null;
                    bitmapPreview = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    imageViewUser.setImageBitmap(new GraphicsUtil().getCircleBitmap(GraphicsUtil.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(filePath,
                            120, 120)));
                    // imageViewUser.setImageBitmap(new
                    // GraphicsUtil().getCircleBitmap(bitmapPreview));
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/temporary_holder.jpg");
                    if (f.exists())
                    {
                        f.delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**GraphicsUtil.java**

```
public class GraphicsUtil
{

    /*
     * Draw image in circular shape Note: change the pixel size if you want
     * image small or large
     */
    public Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Bitmap output;
        Canvas canvas = null;
        final int color = 0xffff0000;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = null;
        if (bitmap.getHeight() > 501)
        {
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(output);
            rect = new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        }
        else
        {
            //System.out.println("output            else =======");
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500, false);
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(output);
            rect = new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        }
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) 1);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
        {
            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

logcat output when clicking image and select image on android 4.4.2 os:-

```
05-08 17:25:55.697: I/System.out(20894): picUri     =======     => null
05-08 17:25:55.698: W/System.err(20894): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 17:25:55.711: W/System.err(20894):    at android.provider.DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(DocumentsContract.java:587)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at com.asiaelites.utils.GraphicsUtil.getPath(GraphicsUtil.java:119)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at com.asiaelites.RegistrationActivity.onActivityResult(RegistrationActivity.java:489)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5446)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3442)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2802)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2274)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-08 17:25:55.712: W/System.err(20894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 17:25:55.713: W/System.err(20894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 17:25:55.713: W/System.err(20894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-08 17:25:55.713: W/System.err(20894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-08 17:25:55.713: W/System.err(20894):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

follow below link :-

[Android Gallery on KitKat returns different Uri for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content)

Comment: It's a known bug in the kitkat if i am not wrong.

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576049/gallery-has-stopped-while-cropping-image-in-kitkat-nexus7/22576780#22576780

Comment: try my solution if you still having problem

Comment: refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261498/android-kitkat-image-crop?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: refer this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261498/android-kitkat-image-crop

Comment: Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(
       Intent.ACTION_PICK,
       android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

     startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 2);

if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
    try {
//     userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
     performCrop(selectedImage);

    } catch (Exception e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
    } 

   }

Comment: This is working with Gallery but not working with Camera... I need for camera.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you got solution but this is for them who still finding for solution.

use this line of code in onActivityResult

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
```

OR Refer this [link for getting URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent).

Just use this code of **getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri)**, Using uri you are having it will **return path of File**.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

// DocumentProvider
if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
// ExternalStorageProvider
if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
final String[] split = docId.split(":");
final String type = split[0];

if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
+ split[1];
}

// TODO handle non-primary volumes
}
// DownloadsProvider
else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
Long.valueOf(id));

return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
}
 // MediaProvider
 else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
 final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
 final String[] split = docId.split(":");
 final String type = split[0];

 Uri contentUri = null;
 if ("image".equals(type)) {
 contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
 } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
 contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
 } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
  contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
 }

final String selection = "_id=?";
final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
selectionArgs);
}
}
// MediaStore (and general)
else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
}
// File
else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
return uri.getPath();
}

return null;
}

/**
* Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
* MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
*
* @param context
* The context.
* @param uri
* The Uri to query.
* @param selection
* (Optional) Filter used in the query.
* @param selectionArgs
* (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
* @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
*/
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

Cursor cursor = null;
final String column = "_data";
final String[] projection = { column };

try {
cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
selection, selectionArgs, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
} finally {
if (cursor != null)
cursor.close();
}
return null;
}

/**
* @param uri
* The Uri to check.
* @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
*/
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
.getAuthority());
}

/**
* @param uri
* The Uri to check.
* @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
*/
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
.getAuthority());
}

/**
* @param uri
* The Uri to check.
* @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
*/
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
.getAuthority());
}
```